# Suggestion of hashtags in UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield, hashtag

I'm building a to-do list and when the user creates a new task, I use a UITextfield for entering task name. What I would like to provide is when the user type # in that UITextField I present a list of tags already created by the user or if the Tag doesn't exist I would create a new one and assign it to that new task.

I have already searched in here and I can't find a similar question with a proper awnser. I can't find a way to only present the suggestions when the # is pressed.

By the way, sorry about my bad english.

Comment: Your English is good. How have you tried to detect the # character being typed?

Comment: @Wain I've tried [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16989673/1350222) this way but I'm getting the # also in the range. And this method doesn't make that only one tag is allowed and when I delete some letter this goes crazy. Also I don't know how to 'autocorrect' when the user doesn't select suggestions,i.e, entering a tag by hand and assume that it already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your containing view controller as a UITextFieldDelegate.  With that in place, you can implement

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

This is called when a digit is typed into the field, so check the replacement string against the hash tag, and create the drop down as appropriate:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if([string isEqualToString:@"#"]) {
        [containingViewController showDropdownListFromElement:textField];

        // Now consume the hash tag by not allowing the addition
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: showing the suggestions in a tableview is not my problem. my problem is finding if the tag entered already exist or if I should create one for the user. What I want is kind the functionality that is implemented in most email client apps where the user enter the email and there are suggestions appearing and if the user doesn't select any of this suggestions the uitextfield "assumes that is a new one".

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  To determine if the typed value exists in your array, can you compare textField.text in the above code to the array using a predicate?

Comment: But how can I select only the text after the #? What if the user backspace? That comparison should be done in the method you refered? what if the user doesn't select any of my suggestions? how can I find if there is a tag in the textfield ?

Comment: Do your tags allow spaces, I assume not, so space or return is the end. You need to think about the string searching and processing.